# Permission denied в PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

Привет. У меня проблемы с PostgreSQL. Установил, создал роль, создал базу, таблицу, дал роли все права на работу с базой и с таблицей:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE flaut TO flautdb;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE searches TO flautdb;
```

Но в PHP получаю ошибку:

> Query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for sequence searches_id_seq

Таблица состоит из двух полей:

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
data JSONB NOT NULL
```

Запрос PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = json_encode($_POST['data'], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    //DB
    $db = getdb();
    $query = "INSERT INTO searches (data) VALUES ('$data') RETURNING id";
    $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
    pg_close($db);
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Кроме таблиц надо разрешить доступ к "searches_id_seq". + посмотрите все таблицы, последовательности, индексы, и прочее, что будет затронуто при работе с Вашими таблицами. Все нужно будет разрешить, если мне не изменяет память

Answer (score 2):

Тип данный serial - это просто синтаксическое сокращение для автоматического создания sequence и его использования как дефолтного значения для поля int.

Сами sequence живут отдельно от таблиц и так же требуют права для своего использования.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO flautdb;
```

Вообще, для работы с правами доступа postgresql необходимо

- или разобраться, что и как вы хотите ограничивать в доступе и соответственно этому создать роли и предоставить права + default privileges для вновь создаваемых объектов
- или изначально создать базу данных для owner'а

  create database dbname owner ownerusername;

и в дальнейшем работать и создавать все объекты именно этим owner'ом. Уже имеющуюся базу можно сменить через reassign owned запросы

Comment: Спасибо! Я создавал базу по [этому](https://community.vscale.io/hc/ru/community/posts/211866305-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-PostgreSQL-%D0%BD%D0%B0-Ubuntu-16-04) мануалу. Но там, видимо, далеко не всё описано. Какие запросы мне нужно отправить Postgre, чтобы пользователь flautdb имел полный доступ к базе flaut?